# How do I create a function in python that accumilates each time in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get zero as a return for salary. I know it may have to do with variable scope but I am lost.

```
'''
Write a program to declare two empty lists one is for name and one for salaries.
Within the for loop ask for employees name and their salaries
and append them into the list accordingly.
Find out the total salary using accumulation concept but you
need to call a function called EvaluateSalary() within the for loop passing the argument
salary for each iteration.

Output : Both of the lists with their items and the total salary.
'''

#Declare name list
nameList = []

#declare salary list
salaryList = []

#declare quit constant
QUIT = "ZZZ" or 000

employeeName = str(input("Please enter an Employee name or ZZZ to quit :         ")).upper()
employeeSalary = float(input("Please enter the salary of the Employee or 000  to quit : "))
```

Below is what im not doing properly. I want it to add the salary input through each pass of the loop.

```
salary = 0
def EvaluateSalary(salary):
    salary = salary + employeeSalary
    return salary

while employeeName != QUIT:
    nameList.append(employeeName)
    salaryList.append(employeeSalary)
    EvaluateSalary(salary)
    employeeName = str(input("Please enter an Employee name or ZZZ to quit : ")).upper()
    employeeSalary = float(input("Please enter the salary of the Employee or 000 to quit : "))

print("Goodbye!")
print(nameList, salaryList, salary)
```

Comment: this isn't python, your code has to be indented properly to work

Comment: It is. I just don't know how to post on here properly

Comment: It was formatting my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Pretend it was indented properly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in terms of scope or the function

Comment: Lol ... when i pretend your code works

Comment: Ok I'll do that later. Thank you. But if you notice anything in the code you see I'm sure you can take an educated guess and give me some hep

Comment: My guess is that function of yours you wanted salary as a global. Thought the code actually is so far away from anything working. I will help you with an answer below.

Comment: Please format your code though so the answer makes sense.

Comment: Ok I just stepped out. When I get back I'll fix it. sorry for the sloppiness. I appreciate the immediate help and I love learning this. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a school assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Although stack overflow is not a place where you ask people to write code for you, i think this post may help new programmers see a code example and learn some techniques, one of which is avoiding globals and/or functional programming techniques.

if I were to re-write your code, I would write it as follows:

```
def input_employees():
    while True:
        name = input(
            "Please enter an Employee name or Hit Enter to quit : "
        ).upper()
        if not name:
            break
        salary = input(
            "Please enter the salary of the Employee or Hit Enter to quit : "
        )
        if not salary:
            break
        yield {'name': name, 'salary': float(salary)}

def sum_salary(employees):
    # this is a guess from your code. my guess is you wanted a salary sum
    return sum([e['salary'] for e in employees])

def main():
    employees = list(input_employees())
    print('Total Salaries:', sum_salary(employees))
    print(employees)

main() # run the main function, ie the script
```

Comment: This looks awesome. Thanks for the help. I cant wait until I am at this level I don't understand a lot of this yet. But I will get there and continue to study what you've shown me here.

Comment: @MichaelVivirito my guess is the hardest pieces in this code are the [yield statement](http://www.python-course.eu/generators.php) and the [list comprehension](http://www.learnpython.org/en/List_Comprehensions). Hopefully those links would clear those pieces up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
salary = 0
def EvaluateSalary(salary):

    salary = salary + employeeSalary
    return salary
```

salary is a global variable. There's no need to pass it to your function, so what you have to pass is employeeSalary.

I think this will work

```
salary = 0
def EvaluateSalary(employeeSalary):

    salary = salary + employeeSalary
```

You don't need to return anything since salary is global, you can access it anywhere from your code.

Method 2:

Without the use of global variables:

```
def EvaluateSalary(employeeSalary, salary):
    salary = salary + employeeSalary
    return salary

salary = 0
while ...whatever...:
    salary = EvaluateSalary(employeeSalary, salary)
    (...)
```

So, you update the value of the global salary in each iteration of while loop, and just keep accummulating.

Comment: Thank you guys and @nhouser for editing my code. This was my first post. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: @myhst when I change the code to what youve shown. And I believe I attempted this prior. I get the following error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'salary' referenced before assignment

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that in Python inside a function, you need to specify global before addressing a global variable. Write "global salary" between the def line and the other.

Comment: is there any way to do this without global. I  just need to know what im doing wrong. even with global im still getting that same error. Also I havent learned about global yet in class. Im just not understanding the error in my logic. I dont think this solution needs global because she wouldve taught is already.

Comment: Make sure you put global salary after the def line, and before the salary = salary (...) thing. It is just to tell python that we are referring to global scope and not local (just within the function scope)

Comment: If you don't want to use global, then you will have to pass also salary and keep passing throughout your code everytime you are in the scope of a function.

Comment: yes I think that is the Idea. Am I way off. I'm totally lost. basically I'm getting the salary as input in a while loop and I was told to create a function to handle to accumulate the salary total. We haven't learned to use the global technique yet. Am I way off?

Comment: Then don't use a global var. I mean, you can pass the salary value to the function as well as the other we have already, for each iteration. It will work as well.

Comment: can you show me an example or point me to something similar. I dont want the answer I just want to know how to solve the problem. What am i missing in what I am writing?

Comment: oh I think I understand. does the input have to be inside the function?

Comment: Reread my answer and check Method 2. While loop is not complete, I hope you have it already done. Just get the things you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, This worked. But I feel like I need a better understanding. I see that I shouldve assigned the salaryTotal to the function. Do you have a youtube video or a link to a specific tutorial that you think will give me a better grasp of what I was missing. I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you again.